# multiple months date picker

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-datepicker

Hi I need some help please,

I am using this plugins [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I have startdate textfield datepicker and 1 input textfield. I want to show multiple months base on my input range number example I will input 15 and my startdate will be 28/06/2018 (DD/MM/YYY) .if I will submit so it will show the month of June and JULY and the day 19th of July will be bold. how can I achieve this ?

```
 $('#startdate').datepicker({

    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
     beforeShowDay: function (date) {

        if (date >= startdate && date <= endate) {
            return [true, 'ui-state-error', ''];
        }
        return [true, '', ''];
     }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="input-small" name="start" />
<span class="add-on">to</span>
<input type="text" class="input-small" name="end" />
```

```
 $('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```